# Is this the correct useage of... including; but not only,

Tags: phrases, idioms, word-usage

Is this the correct useage of, *"every possible accessory and trimming a body could desire to adorn their costumes with, including; but not only, brightly colored ribbons, buttons, needles of brass and threads of fine silk"*

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon strikes me as grammatically incorrect, but people like to do some strange things with semicolons around here, so who am I to say.

However, your question seems moot since the "but not only" part is completely redundant and can be removed. Saying "Every possible accessory... including X" already implies that there are other things you're not listing.  So I would say the correct answer is:

> "...every possible accessory and trimming a body could desire to adorn their costumes, including brightly colored ribbons, buttons, needles of brass and threads of fine silk..."

Comment: And the semicolon. :(

Comment: *"but not only" part is completely redundant?* -- No, neither grammar nor semantics says so. About 1,960,000,000 results: https://www.google.com/#q=%22including+but+not+limited+to%22

Comment: Semicolon is not grammar, at least not in the strictest terms.

Comment: @Kris note that I never said "including but not limited to" is *always* redundant. I said it's redundant in this case because of the aforementioned "every possible accessory".

Comment: The question, though, is about the expression 'including but not only' -- digressing from that is not advisable.

Comment: I disagree; the question is about "the correct usage" of it. The correct usage of a phrase includes the context and when NOT to use it.

Comment: And there's an important purpose for which the but clause is included.

Comment: Please feel free to include that important purpose in your answer, as I will not respond to any further nitpickery on this one.